# When I connect to VPN, I'm losing the Internet

Tags: 16.04, internet, vpn

If I connect to the VPN. I'm losing the internet.

After connecting to the VPN, If the check ping 4.2.2.2 It is working as expected and it showing the Internet is transferring. But I could not access it.

Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a DNS issue and that the VPN server is not properly set up to use any particular DNS server.

If you sre using openVPN, the server configuration file '/etc/openvpn/server.conf' might need to state DNS configurations.

My server configuration file contains following lines:

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

allowing DNS lookup from Googles servers.

Remember, if you alter this in the config file, you may have to restart the VPN server.